# Why do I get incorrect values when implementing HMAC-SHA256?

Tags: rust, sha256, hmac

I'm trying to make a function in Rust that will return a HMAC-SHA256 digest. I've been working from the description at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) and [RFC 2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104).

I've been struggling with returning the correct HMAC. I'm using [ring](https://www.briansmith.org/rustdoc/ring/) for the SHA256 digests but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get the right result. I suspect it might have something to do with `.as_ref().to_vec()` conversions. Even if that's true, I don't know how to continue from that. Not everything from RFC 2104 is implemented in the following code, but it highlights my issue.

```
extern crate ring;
use ring::{digest, test};

pub fn hmac(k: Vec<u8>, mut m: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    // Initialize ipad and opad as byte vectors with SHA256 blocksize
    let ipad = vec![0x5C; 64];
    let opad = vec![0x36; 64];
    // iround and oround are used to seperate the two steps with XORing
    let mut iround = vec![];
    let mut oround = vec![];

    for count in 0..k.len() {
        iround.push(k[count] ^ ipad[count]);
        oround.push(k[count] ^ opad[count]);
    }

    iround.append(&mut m); // m is emptied here
    iround = (digest::digest(&digest::SHA256, &iround).as_ref()).to_vec();
    oround.append(&mut iround); // iround is emptied here
    oround = (digest::digest(&digest::SHA256, &oround).as_ref()).to_vec();
    let hashed_mac = oround.to_vec();

    return hashed_mac;
}

#[test]
fn test_hmac_digest() {
    let k = vec![0x61; 64];
    let m = vec![0x62; 64];
    let actual = hmac(k, m);
    // Expected value taken from: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output
    let expected = test::from_hex("f6cbb37b326d36f2f27d294ac3bb46a6aac29c1c9936b985576041bfb338ae70").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(actual, expected);
}
```

These are the digests:

```
Actual = [139, 141, 144, 52, 11, 3, 48, 112, 117, 7, 56, 151, 163, 65, 152, 195, 163, 164, 26, 250, 178, 100, 187, 230, 89, 61, 191, 164, 146, 228, 180, 62]

Expected = [246, 203, 179, 123, 50, 109, 54, 242, 242, 125, 41, 74, 195, 187, 70, 166, 170, 194, 156, 28, 153, 54, 185, 133, 87, 96, 65, 191, 179, 56, 174, 112]
```

Comment: *I suspect it might have something to do with `.as_ref().to_vec()` conversions* — why do you suspect that?

Comment: The `.as_ref()` should return a byte slice `&[u8]` and that there could be a problem with converting that to a `Vec<u8>`. I tried with `.extend_from_slice()`, instead of `.append()` (to get rid of the conversion) earlier today, had no luck with that either.

Comment: You just swapped inner and outer padding, it's working otherwise.

Comment: That is next level idiocy. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you have swapped the bytes for the inner and outer padding. Refer back to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation):

```
o_key_pad = key xor [0x5c * blockSize]   //Outer padded key
i_key_pad = key xor [0x36 * blockSize]   //Inner padded key
```

Here's what my take on the function would look like. I believe it has less allocation:

```
extern crate ring;

use ring::{digest, test};

const BLOCK_SIZE: usize = 64;

pub fn hmac(k: &[u8], m: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    assert_eq!(k.len(), BLOCK_SIZE);

    let mut i_key_pad: Vec<_> = k.iter().map(|&k| k ^ 0x36).collect();
    let mut o_key_pad: Vec<_> = k.iter().map(|&k| k ^ 0x5C).collect();

    i_key_pad.extend_from_slice(m);

    let hash = |v| digest::digest(&digest::SHA256, v);

    let a = hash(&i_key_pad);

    o_key_pad.extend_from_slice(a.as_ref());

    hash(&o_key_pad).as_ref().to_vec()
}

#[test]
fn test_hmac_digest() {
    let k = [0x61; BLOCK_SIZE];
    let m = [0x62; BLOCK_SIZE];
    let actual = hmac(&k, &m);

    // Expected value taken from: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output
    let expected = test::from_hex("f6cbb37b326d36f2f27d294ac3bb46a6aac29c1c9936b985576041bfb338ae70").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(actual, expected);
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I'm fairly new to Rust and haven't seen `let hash = |v| digest::digest(&digest::SHA256, v);`. Is that a shorthand way of writing a function?

Comment: @brycx This is the syntax to define a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html).  It's similar to a function, except that it can capture variables from the local scope.  This particular closure doesn't close over any local variables, so it could have been written as a function, too.