# The result of HMAC<Sha256> differs from another implementation

Tags: cryptography, rust, sha256, hmac

I am attempting to implement HMAC verification using SHA256 to interact with an API. I've found the [hmac](https://docs.rs/hmac/0.6.2/hmac/) and [sha2](https://docs.rs/sha2/0.7.1/sha2/) crates, and according to their examples they will work perfectly for my purposes.

I have this code:

```
extern crate hmac;
extern crate sha2;

use hmac::{Hmac, Mac};
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};

pub fn verify(message: &[u8], code: &[u8], key: &[u8]) -> bool {
    type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;

    let mut mac = HmacSha256::new_varkey(key).unwrap();
    mac.input(message);

    let result = mac.result().code();
    return result == code;
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use verify;
    #[test]
    fn should_work() {
        assert!(verify(
          b"code=0907a61c0c8d55e99db179b68161bc00&shop=some-shop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1337178173",
          b"4712bf92ffc2917d15a2f5a273e39f0116667419aa4b6ac0b3baaf26fa3c4d20",
          b"hush"
        ), "Returned false with correct parameters!");
    }

    #[test]
    fn shouldnt_work() {
        assert!(
            !verify(
                b"things=things&stuff=this_is_pod_racing",
                b"3b3f62798a09c78hjbjsakbycut^%9n29ddeb8f6862b42c7eb6fa65cf2a8cade",
                b"mysecu)reAn111eecretB"
            ),
            "Returned true with incorrect parameters!"
        );
    }
}
```

`cargo test` should show a valid HMAC verification, and an invalid one.

Unfortunately, the results given from the `verify` function disagree with the result from online HMAC generators. As an example, with the message `code=0907a61c0c8d55e99db179b68161bc00&shop=some-shop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1337178173` and key `hush`, this [online](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html) HMAC generator indicates the hash should be `4712bf92ffc2917d15a2f5a273e39f0116667419aa4b6ac0b3baaf26fa3c4d20`, but this causes my tests to fail, and printing out the result confirms that the hash is not correct.

I've confirmed that the results of my byte-string literals are indeed their ASCII equivalents, and otherwise I'm performing this process almost exactly like the examples demonstrate.

I will not be using `result == code` in the final version due to side-channel attacks, that is just to make my debugging life a little easier.

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "crypto"
version = "0.1.0"


[dependencies]
hmac = "0.6.2"
sha2 = "0.7.1"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> 4712bf92ffc2917d15a2f5a273e39f0116667419aa4b6ac0b3baaf26fa3c4d20
> ```

This isn't supposed to be treated as an ASCII bytestring. This is a *hex-encoding* of the raw bytes to an easily human-readable format. You need to properly match encodings:

```
extern crate hmac;
extern crate sha2;
extern crate hex;

use hmac::{Hmac, Mac};
use sha2::Sha256;

pub fn verify(message: &[u8], code: &str, key: &[u8]) -> bool {
    type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;

    let mut mac = HmacSha256::new_varkey(key).unwrap();
    mac.input(message);

    let result = mac.result().code();

    let r2 = hex::encode(&result);

    r2 == code
}

#[test]
fn should_work() {
    assert!(verify(
        b"code=0907a61c0c8d55e99db179b68161bc00&shop=some-shop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1337178173",
        "4712bf92ffc2917d15a2f5a273e39f0116667419aa4b6ac0b3baaf26fa3c4d20",
        b"hush"
    ), "Returned false with correct parameters!");
}

#[test]
fn shouldnt_work() {
    assert!(
        !verify(
            b"things=things&stuff=this_is_pod_racing",
            "3b3f62798a09c78hjbjsakbycut^%9n29ddeb8f6862b42c7eb6fa65cf2a8cade",
            b"mysecu)reAn111eecretB"
        ),
        "Returned true with incorrect parameters!"
    );
}
```

See also:

- [How do I convert a string to hex in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27492969/155423)
- [Why do I get incorrect values when implementing HMAC-SHA256?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48630814/155423)
- [Using PBKDF2 key derivation to properly create user-readable salt with rust-crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49101377/155423)